# Access body element from content page via a nested master page

Tags: asp.net

All I want to do is access the `<body>` element from the code-behind of a content page and add a class name to it.

I have a top-level master page with the `<body>` element in it. Then I have a nested master page which is the master page for the content page. From the code behind of the content page I want to add a class name to the body element. That's all.

I have this in the top-level master:

```
<body id="bodyNode" runat="server">
```

I added this to the code-behind for the content page:

```
Master.bodyNode.Attributes.add("class", "home-page");
```

And I get a message that:

> System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'bodyNode

If I add this to the aspx content page:

```
<% @ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

The message then changes to:

> bodyNode is inaccessible due to its protection level

Please advise, I've wasted like 2 hours on what feels like something that should be really simple to do :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

once you have set runat="server" for your body node, you have to access it using the HTMLControls namespace.  try this.

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
//Inject onload and unload
HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("bodyNode");
body.Attributes.Add("class", "home-page");   
}
```

**EDIT**
Your problem is that you have nested master pages.

Since the "body" tag is in your top level master page, `Master.FindControl()` won't work, as that is looking in the nested master page.

What you need to do is use `Master.Master.FindControl()`, or recursively loop through your master pages, going up until `Master.Master` is null (as then you know you are at the top level master page) and then calling `FindControl()` on that.

Comment: You can also set a public property to allow you to access the body without cutting and pasting this code on all your content pages

Comment: Thanks, I added this but the exception has now changed to: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' the line generating this is 'body.Attributes.Add("class", "home-page");' although there is no red-underlining in the actual file to indicate a problem..?

Comment: this means that "body" is null. Check that the line above is correctly finding it by putting a breakpoint after it. You will probably find that it isn't. 

Try running Master.FindControl("bodyNode") in immediate mode (once you hit the breakpoint) and see what it returns, i will test and re-answer shortly

Comment: that works Lerxst, but I have an element in the masterpage, and I want to show it in all pages but one, so when I add this :   Master.FindControl("headerbanner").Visible = false; it wont work , because the compiler will parse the content page then the master page, and in the masterpage I set the Visible True

Comment: I know that it is explicitly stated in @Lerxst first sentence of stating 'once you have set runat="server" for your body node', I overlooked this and was getting the same object reference error as danwellman. Once this was in there, with <<bodyNode>> name also as the <body id="bodyNode" runat="server"> this worked like a charm. Thanks @Lerxst!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a public property to the code behind of the master page that would allow access to the body tag that is part of the master page.  And then call that property from the content page.