# Change MasterPage portion of page title programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to overwrite the MasterPage title. NOTE: I'm not talking about setting a portion of the title from the content page.

I have this in my MasterPage:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Site | <% = Page.Title %></title>
</head>
```

Which, in combination with this on my content pages...

```
<%@ Page Title="Content page title" ... %>
```

delivers the following to the user:

`<title>My Site | Content page title</title>`, which is great 99.9% of the time. However, I would like to be able to change the entire title delivered to the client so that it does not include the portion specified in the head of the MasterPage, IE: `<title>Special content page</title>`

Is it possible to change the entire page title from the content page programmatically? I do not want to change the configuration of the MasterPage or use a different MasterPage.

**EDIT:** I also need to be able to implement this without changing existing content pages. Sorry I didn't state this explicitly. I assumed it would be understood

Comment: @ViewBag.Title = someStringReference  Then you can just specify in each of your controllers to modify the title based on your definition. Or you could have the change pulled directly out of a Model, a few choices...

Comment: Does calling this.Page.Title = "Special content page" in your codebehind change the whole title?

Comment: Can you direct me toward any examples? I'm new to this and I'm not sure what you mean by "controllers" or "Model"

Comment: @GregD No, same result.

Answer (score 2):

Change your master page markup to

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title><asp:Literal ID="MasterPageTitle" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
```

In your masterpage.cs

```
public string ExplicitTitle { get; set; }

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ExplicitTitle))
    {
        this.MasterPageTitle.Text = "My Site | " + Page.Title;
    }
    else
    {
        this.MasterPageTitle.Text = this.ExplicitTitle;
    }
}
```

In your "Special content page" add the this to Page_PreRender

```
((MySiteMaster)this.Master).ExplicitTitle = "Special content title";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches depending on which form of ASP.Net you're using.

If you're using MVC, then simple set a property called "PageTitle" in your ViewBag and then reference it in your Master Page:

In HomeController.cs

```
@ViewBag.PageTitle = 'Overridden Title'
```

In your Master Page:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Site | <% = @ViewBag.PageTitle %></title>
</head>
```

If you're using a WebForms based application, you can do this by first exposing the html title through "hybrid server control"

In your master page, change things to:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title id="MasterTitle" runat="server"></title>
</head>
```

Then in your child pages, you add a type reference to your master page up at the top:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Templates/YourMasterPage.master" %>
```

In your child page code behind, you now have access through.

```
Master.MasterTitle.Text = "Overridden Title";
```

Comment: I'm using WebForms.

I get the following error: 'SiteMaster.MasterTitle' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @brainbolt Accessing the root controls (head, body, etc.) are a bit trickier than basic webcontrols in this regard. Check out this answer, it should have enough information for you to set things up properly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866208/access-body-element-from-content-page-via-a-nested-master-page

Comment: Ok, so I added the following to the page_load of the content page codebehind: `HtmlTitle title = (HtmlTitle)Master.FindControl("MasterTitle");` `title.Text = "Overridden Title";` but I still get `<title>My Site | Overridden Title</title>` delivered to the client...

Comment: What does your title element currently look like, do you have text in there?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're asking. On the master page the title element looks like what I posted in my original question. After adding the code in my previous comment, the client receives `<title>My Site | Overridden Title</title>`

Comment: Oh I see, I had a typo. Since you're using webforms, remove the <% Page.Title %> portion and just leave the title. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: That does work, but it is not what I'm looking for. This would force me to change every existing content page. I'm going to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2012, in your child pages if using WebForms, you change absolutely nothing in your Master Page.  Everything can now be done through your child pages:

The following statement goes at the very top of your child page code:

```
`<%@ Page Title="Insert Your Title here" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SomeChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeProject.WebForm1" %>`
```

Answer (score 0):

*In Master Page*

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMasterTitle"
     runat="server"/>
</title>
```

*In Child Page*

```
<asp:Content ID="contentChildTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMasterTitle"
    runat="server">
    <asp:literal ..... etc ... />
</asp:Content>
```

or without use of content/placeholder

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Title = "Child Title"
End Sub
```